# Linux command - find files based on extension and date of creation

Tags: linux, terminal, find

How to find all files in all folders (starting from the root `/`) ending with *.ts that are made in last 15 days?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -name '*.ts' -a -mtime -15
```

Comment: `-a` is implied and can be dropped in this instance.

Comment: Also, notice that `mtime` isn't really "time when the file was made", just when it was modified. `find` (and many file systems) don't support the notion of "file creation time".